# Ingress vs mysqli_queries in php

Tags: php

In php 7 documentation i found new and easy methods to connect sql database using functions which start with ingress,like ingress_query(). I would like to know whether it is a good practice to use these functions or should i continue using mysqli_connect()
link of documentation is
http://php.net/manual/en/function.ingres-fetch-assoc.php

Comment: Ingres is it's own database. It's not mysql and the built in functions shouldn't be compatible. You would use the ingres functions for connections to an ingres database and mysqli functions for using mysql database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters: Ingress is not mySQL, so you cannot use `ingress_*` functions to connect to mySQL database. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

Also note that:

> This extension has been moved to the » PECL repository and is no
>   longer bundled with PHP as of PHP 5.1.0.

Comment: yeah sorry. i admit its a question posted without proper search.